# Calculating π using the Gregory Leibniz series until n terms

Tags: code-golf, sequence, pi

> based off my previous challenge, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) wikipedia article, and a Scratch project

Your task: given `i`, calculate \$\pi\$ till `i` terms of the Gregory-Leibniz series.

The series:

$$\pi=\frac{4}{1}-\frac{4}{3}+\frac{4}{5}-\frac{4}{7}+\frac{4}{9}-...$$

Here, `4/1` is the first term, `-4/3` is the second, `4/5` is the second and so on.

Note that for the nth term,

- $$\text S_n = \frac{4 \times (-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}$$
- $$\pi_n = \text S_1 + \text S_2 + ... + \text S_n,$$
  where \$\pi_n\$ is \$\pi\$ approximated to \$n\$ terms.

Test cases:

```
In - Out
1 - 4
2 - 2.66666667
3 - 3.46666667
4 - 2.8952381
```

Floating point issues are OK.

You may not calculate infinite terms of pi using this as we are calculating a number rather than terms of a series here.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins!

**EDIT:** It's strange that this question got some new... activity.

Comment: _You may not calculate infinite terms of pi [...]_ -> Does that mean that we can't use [standard sequence I/O](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info)? If so, I don't understand why.

Comment: @Arnauld I think what he meant to say is that the challenge is to output the terms of the Gregory Leibniz sequence, and not the (potentially infinite) digits of pi itself.

Comment: Nope. Here pi is being calculated by adding up the terms of the series. So you add up the terms, and then print the approx. of pi when summing up

Comment: I don't understand why we cannot output \$\pi_n\$ with standard [tag:sequence] I/O (this would mean also allowing output of approximations of \$\pi\$ up to \$n\$ terms or outputting more approximations without end).

Comment: Normally, I would have let you as you'd be printing terms of a series, but here we are printing approximations. Why should we print all approximations to a certain term? When calculating pi, we aim for the most accurate, not keeping a log of inaccurate periods.

Comment: *not keeping a log of inaccurate approximations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
RḤ’4÷Ṛḅ-
```

A monadic Link that accepts a positive integer, \$n\$, and yields a floating point number, \$\pi_n\$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9qZWxsef//UuG4pOKAmTTDt@G5muG4hS3///8z)**

#### How?

```
RḤ’4÷Ṛḅ- - Link: positive integer, n
R        - range n           -> [1,2,3,...,n]
 Ḥ       - double            -> [2,4,6,...,2n]
  ’      - decrement         -> [1,3,5,...,2n-1]
   4     - 4
    ÷    - divide            -> [4/1,4/3,4/5,...,4/(2n-1)]
     Ṛ   - reverse           -> [4/(2n-1),...,4/5,4/3,4/1]
       - - -1
      ḅ  - convert from base -> (-1)^(n-1)*4/(2n-1)+...+1*4/5+-1*4/3+1*4/1 = pi_n
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>14</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
L·<z··R®β
```

-5 bytes porting [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252054/52210)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f59B2myoTraBD685t@v/fGAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R/i6mevpPCobZKCkr3ff59D222qTLSCDq07t@m/zn8A).

**Original 14 bytes answer:**

```
0λè®N>m4*N·</+
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4NzuwysOrfOzyzXR8ju03UZf@/9/YwA) or [verify the infinite sequence](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4NzuQ@v87HJNtPwObbfR1649tOz/fwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
L          # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
 ·         # Double each value: [2,4,6,...,2n]
  <        # Decrease each by 1: [1,3,5,...,2n-1]
   z       # Calculate 1/z for each: [1,1/3,1/5,...,1/(2n-1)]
    4*     # Multiply by 4: [4,4/3,4/5,...,4/(2n-1)]
      R    # Reverse the list: [4/(2n-1),...,4/5,4/3,4]
       ®β  # Convert it from a base-(-1) list to a base-10 integer:
           #  (-1)^(n-1)*4/(2n-1) + ... + 1*4/5 + -1*4/3 + 1*4/1
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

The 14-byter is pretty similar as [my 05AB1E answer of the previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251921/52210).

```python
 λ         # Start a recursive environment,
  è        # to calculate a(input)
           # (which is output implicitly afterwards)
0          # Start with a(0)=0
           # Where every following a(n) is calculated by:
           #  (implicitly push the previous term a(n-1))
   ®N>m    #  Push (-1) to the power (n+1)
       4*  #  Multiply it by 4
   N·<     #  Push 2n-1
   /       #  Divide the earlier 4*(-1)**(n+1) by this (2n-1)
    +      #  Add it to the previous term a(n-1)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <del>36</del> 35 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=1:n and 4/k-f(n-1,k+2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADAWV/RscQSRZ1IeAwG0QYthLD4erwrX7uzbL1H9/j3CB6EkjNWwEuAfU46omhDaVpVj7kCAwtUL9eJhsAsyo5DqSwNmSAiK9V/)

-1 thanks to Mukundan314.

Comment: [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAgDADAWV/RscQSRZ1IeAwG0QYthLD4erwrX7uzbL1H9/j3CB6EkjNWwEuAfU46omhDaVpVj7kCAwtUL9eJhsAsyo5DqSwNmSAiK9V/)

Comment: FWIW, we can accelerate the convergence: (not golfed) https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVjsFugzAQRO9I_MOIXOzEJHXSExJ_kCrHHggHkCFaQRbHhEPy9V0aqraWT7Mzb2aFzwczGj9SP_AWx4Zqpic8beOIpyty7A9Y4WMa76gbDM7FURy1eV9da1eBTZfbjFGxw_uuS1vFqTXdZq_jyDsDJ4DirVwLyqBo1aTRDgETiBEqvjRKLroUcyC-q-QU6EJc9Yn-kdZCGRufJ2eeRemWPP3mrcGMyOII8hbMmY_D4BMD0i_dWRniCpuVi2_Z5iReeGxgsYMKSHF7LfQGN4Mw9zzJq2-_fKvLv0X_xn0BgdxbKQ==&lang=python

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>31</s> 28 bytes

*Edit: -3 bytes thanks to [@Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen).*

```
\(n,m=2*1:n-1)sum(4i/1i^m/m)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhZ7YjTydHJtjbQMrfJ0DTWLS3M1TDL1DTPjcvVzNSFKNqdpGGpypWkYgQhjEGEClVmwAEIDAA)

Uses
$$ (-1)^{n+1} = -1 \times (-1)^{n} = i^2\times i^{-2n} = i^{-2n+2} = i \times i^{-(2n-1)}$$
And then
$$\text S_n = \frac{4 \times (-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1} = \frac{\frac{4i}{i^{2n-1}} }{2n-1} $$

Comment: Alternative 28 byte version: `\(n)sum(4/(1:n*2-1)*c(1,-1))` (generates a warning for odd n, but still computes the correct answer)

Comment: Nevermind, I can't make it work for n=1 :(

Comment: [28 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhZ7YjTydHJtjbQMrfJ0DTWLS3M1TDL1DTPjcvVzNSFKNqdpGGpypWkYgQhjEGEClVmwAEIDAA) (and works for n=1)...

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>63</s></sup> 60 bytes

```c
float f(n){float m=4,p=1,d=1;for(;n--;d+=2,m=-m)p+=m/d;--p;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLboMwELznK1ZIkexgk/JIm8h1L1W/ouRAjZ2iBoMwUlERv15qMKWPlWytZ2fGuyvoRYhxVNcqa0EhjXuXljwhNQ9JzkOmqgYxTSnLfR6RktMS1z4v9zmjtGbDWGjLzwqNMPQbsOEsZFdL0cr8@Qwc@oRAFNy6uCMQB8maR8HxdIjiYziwWS4qbVoQr1mzs7cUb7JxHl7aPUVpd3q05@AR@P2OvUVtuwU0tVToXHZWdsOW9B5M8SErhb47w/sF2K0IA9@f2Xg2c/NMMTm21s1Z@RCyteTGNbaoUIv/49Li6ypm9Zn9ca0zM2uzF4MMUJDYdhpKevih1Y0lKuRtc6APsFWwNam2C2gJGLLuaDI6L/8Pm2H8FOqaXcxI378A)

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to [jdt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/jdt)!!!*

Comment: `float f(n){float m=4,p=1,d=1;for(;n--;d+=2,m=-m)p+=m/d;--p;}`

Comment: @jdt Nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

## Excel, <s>51</s> 48 bytes

<sup>Saved 3 bytes thanks to some clever math from [JvdV](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252030/calculating-pi-using-the-gregory-leibniz-series-until-n-terms/252132?noredirect=1#comment561841_252132)</sup>

```
=LET(s,SEQUENCE(A1),SUM((8*ISODD(s)-4)/(2*s-1)))
```

Input is in the cell A1. Output is wherever the formula is.

- `LET(s,SEQUENCE(A1)` defines `s` to be an array of numbers from 1 to the value in A1. This is what lets us calculate the first *n* terms.
- `(8*ISODD(s)-4)` creates an array of the same sized filled with `4, -4, 4, -4, ...`. The only trick is that `ISODD()` returns a boolean and Excel turns TRUE into 1 and FALSE into 0 when you force it to do math. That means it becomes an array of `8-4, 0-4, 8-4, 0-4, ...` which then simplifies as shown above.
- `(2*s-1)` creates an array of the same size filled with `1, 3, 5, 7, ...`
- `SUM((~)/(~))` divides the first array by the second (giving us each term in the sequence) and then adds them up.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Nice. If you'd rely on math you can scratch the `IF()` saving two bytes using `=LET(s,SEQUENCE(A1),SUM((-4+8*ISODD(s))/(2*s-1)))`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>41</s></sup> 39 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:x and(x%2*4-2)/(x-.5)+f(x-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYvLDsIgEEX3fMVsTEEFw6O2NvoxmEokaYEUTOjXI63xLu7kzJkJa3p7J0sxj0nPz1FDHjJoN@J8EEdFBbngTFlLTqZOToqdg18SxDUi4xewYN0GLKbRugFBjXXhDP6T4AGWxTDZhBug0JDdhsW6hA3eul4SUpWZvE64vhC4A3/RjhRe1wqJ2oJdf@mQrCiZ@qPabX9rhez5Fw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 30 bytes

```
f(n)=∑_{k=1}^n4(-1)^k/(1-2k)
```

Pretty self-explanatory.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xjdsckqop8)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ksfom64prc)

Comment: Congrats - This is *my* first time seeing a desmos answer...

Comment: @py3programmer If you enjoy them, I got [many more](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a96039%20is%3aanswer%20desmos)!

Comment: It is true... but I suppose Desmos only works on math-related questions...

Comment: @py3programmer Yeah true, Desmos works really well on math-related decision problems especially.

Comment: True, because, after all, Desmos *is* a graphing calculator, but I'm surprised it can be used as a code-golfing language!

Comment: @py3programmer Yep! It's a surprisingly powerful tool in solving many coding challenges, and surprisingly golfy too.

Comment: Btw if you want to learn more about golfing in Desmos you may want to pay a visit to the [Desmos tips page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230100/tips-for-code-golfing-in-desmos)

Comment: Thing is, I *do* use Desmos, but not for code-golfing purposes.

Comment: More like only for recreational mathematics.

Comment: @py3programmer Yep I do too! I use my recreational knowledge of Desmos to golf in Desmos.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139501/discussion-between-py3programmer-and-aiden-chow).

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-mx`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
4*JpU /(UÑÄ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW14&code=NCpKcFUgLyhV0cQ&input=NA)

### Without Flags, 11 bytes

```
Ç±Z4/°ZÃÔìJ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=x7FaNC%2bwWsPU7Eo&input=Mw)

```
4*JpU /(UÑÄ     :Implicit map of each U in the range [0,input)
4*              :Multiply 4 by
  J             :-1
   pU           :Raised to the power of U
      /(        :Divide by
        UÑ      :U times 2
          Ä     :Plus 1
                :Implicit output of sum of resulting array
```

```
Ç±Z4/°ZÃÔìJ     :Implicit input of integer U
Ç               :Map each Z in the range [0,U)
 ±Z             :  Increment Z by itself
   4/           :  Divide 4 by
     °Z         :  Z, prefix incremented
       Ã        :End map
        Ô       :Reverse
         ì      :Convert from digit array in base
          J     :  -1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `ḋ`, 10 bytes

```
4ÞNÞ∞d‹/¦i
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuIsiLCIiLCI0w55Ow57iiJ5k4oC5L8KmaSIsIiIsIjUiXQ==)

```
4          # 4
 ÞN        # [4, -4, 4, -4, 4, -4...
   Þ∞      # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...
     d     # [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12...
      ‹    # [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11...
       /   # [4/1, -4/3, 4/5, -4/7...
        ¦  # Take the cumulative sums of that
         i # Index the input into that
```

Comment: "_You may not calculate infinite terms of pi using this as we are calculating a number rather than terms of a series here._"

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 28 bytes

```hs
f n=foldr((-).(2/))0[1/2..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzYtPyelSENDV1NPw0hfU9Mg2lDfSE8vL/Z/bmJmnoKtQm5iga9CQVFmXomCCoijkKYQbaCnZxn7HwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `ḋ`, 13 bytes

Flag `ḋ` prints out rationals in their decimal form

```
ƛ4nd‹/un›e*;∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuIsiLCIiLCLGmzRuZOKAuS91buKAumUqO+KIkSIsIiIsIjQiXQ==)

**Explanation:**

```
ƛ4nd‹/un›e*;∑
ƛ          ;    Map trough range of input
 4nd‹/          Divide four by 2n-1
      un›e*     Raise -1 to the n+1 and multiply
            ∑   Sum the fractions
```

[Another 13 byter: `ƛ4nd‹/k-ni*;∑`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuIsiLCIiLCLGmzRuZOKAuS9rLW5pKjviiJEiLCIiLCI0Il0=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `koszul math.unicode`, 51 bytes

```factor
[ [1,b] [ dup 1 + -1^ 4 * swap 2 * 1 - / ] map Σ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYy9CsIwGEX3PsWd1VaiTgquxcVFnEKEmH7V0pjE/CD6Or6PrxSDbvecA7eXKlqfj4fdvl3jJuO1SWZQtqM/eGkuFDCSN6R/CqMNr6QR6J7IqBKdpxifzg8mYlNVy8zB2ewswNElB4YpanbCChOEh3RYlMFQYw5RHh0@b4ispNbY9trKiCZ/AQ)

- `[1,b] [ ... ] map Σ` Map each integer in 1..input using `[ ... ]` and add them together.
- `dup 1 + -1^ 4 * swap 2 * 1 - /` Just a straight translation of $$\text S_n = \frac{4 \times (-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1}$$
  Here's how the data stack looks arriving at the second term to add together:

```
       ! 2
dup    ! 2 2
1      ! 2 2 1
+      ! 2 3
-1^    ! 2 -1
4      ! 2 -1 4
*      ! 2 -4
swap   ! -4 2
2      ! -4 2 2
*      ! -4 4
1      ! -4 4 1
-      ! -4 3
/      ! -1-1/3
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 60 bytes

```
function a(j)
do i=1,j
a=a+4.0*(-1)**(i+1)/(2*i-1)
enddo
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZDNDsIgEITvPMUeAbGVWn@TPgxa2qwoNJTGx68bUOewGTbDN4QhxBSN345DMesUwxjNCyZkQEKf7GgjXK/g8iJa81SToYhNZR/tvDzTzFsBHfC6rXYKmupYdFKwr9q/b6rz5dDsz7oWDDKvD@A6rZZbWHzPvyzV46vTIgey3hGT5VJJAU6B4U6UWf/KXQlb3xORZX8PPhn0M6zD4u8Jg6crD8GoEanxwUxnNvRaybdaSMlxo0XNG4l0ZAQiDs01M7@/sn4A)

Mostly just exploiting implicit typing so no need to declare variable types. Also saves 1 byte by removing the space between end and do.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

*-1 thanks to a clever rearrangement by [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)*

```
Ḟ`-↑M/İ14
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@GOeQm6j9om@uof2WBo8v//f2MA)

#### Explanation

Husk's reversed operand order for subtraction really hurts here, but at least Dominic found a nice workaround for the reversed division.

```
Ḟ`-↑M/İ14
      İ1   Infinite list of positive odd numbers
        4  Integer 4
    M      For each element in the first argument,
     /     divide the second argument by it
   ↑       Take the first N elements, where N is the program's argument
Ḟ          Right-fold the resulting list
 `-        on subtraction
```

Comment: ...but you can avoid one of the reversed operands here by using ```M``` instead of ```m``` for [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@GOeQm6j9om@uof2WBo8v//fxMA)...

Comment: (I had to golf this just to let it [beat Fig](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252260/95126)...

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 47 bytes

```c
float f(n){return--n?(4.-n%2*8)/(n-~n)+f(n):4;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/bToNAEH3ufsUJhmSxu70BSZW2xhhf@wOFB1wWS2yHht0akgZ/HZdqrA9zP3PmjJLvSvV9eahzi5JTcGm0PTckJT3xaCLJX9wvgykn@UXBeAA8RknX31WkDudCY3XM7X6y37Bbx9iiqocWq8iyY14R/6yrImAXNvq5o9uTVlYXuwxrXLB93gpEAssJpggF4sWQzGOBcBZd01mMLmEjVZOxUPu8cU6rD93ssl10JfHS9nWRtg8vzmJP4H8desNyWTfgThHI4eeJC6s1ogTjMQVw0n61GTcd3nQbo1Pj8CX3/AJyA7@Eb1Jy5CRgxJ@EMn8z3EDe3qIswApzLeNs4OlY138D)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 18 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
(4×¯1*⍳)+.÷(1+2×⍳)
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=e9Q31dNf4VHbBAUDAA&c=0zA5PP3QekOtR72bNbX1Dm/XMNQ2OjwdxAMA&f=Szu0QsFQwUjBWMFEwRQA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog-extended&m=train&n=f)

A tacit function.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
ＩΣＥＮ×Ｘ±¹ι∕⁴⊕⊗ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYi7CoNAEEV/xfIKpgjYpdTGIiIkPzCuQzKwD1lnzedPtvDC4XCu@1J2ibzZkiUqBjoUrxLwpB1T3IvOJayc0XbNWwIfWNKv5swfUsa93lIZ5ZSN0XfNFF3mwFF5w5jK6qulvfYw6@12@j8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   Ｎ            Input `n` as a number
  Ｅ             Map over implicit range
       ¹        Literal integer `1`
      ±         Negated
     Ｘ          Raised to power
        ι       Current value
    ×           Multiplied by
          ⁴     Literal integer `4`
         ∕      Divided by
             ι  Current value
            ⊗   Doubled
           ⊕    Incremented
 Σ              Take the sum
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 36 bytes

```hs
f i=g[1,3..i*2]
g(h:t)=4/h-g t
g[]=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYnLCYQwFADvqeIdVfSZn7sqpAQrCEFy0CSsiqzpP4riHAaG8fb4TcuS0gxBOc1KgRgKbojLfB9zJWtfOYjEaaNoWm3YQMFq92GEbP@HLeKcg6aIjJrEoAJJ@GWOn4cvEVcKlG/K@7Zdw0XLTg)

I think it's quite self descriptive due to Haskell feature of describing something.

I try to visualize what *g* does, pretty simple : taking a list of *i* denominators but all positive...

```hs
[1,      3,      5,      7]
                       4/7
               4/5 -  (4/7)
 4 - ( 4/3 - ( 4/5 -  (4/7)))

hence the signs result alternating
 4 -   4/3 +   4/5 -   4/7
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 26 bytes

```
Tr[4I^#/I/#&[2Range@#-1]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P6Qo2sQzTlnfU19ZLdooKDEvPdVBWdcwNlbtv0t@tEJAUWZeSXR1WnRWrI6CXzSIjq0FMquzdAx1TGoVYv8DAA)

Unnamed function that takes a positive integer argument and returns an exact fraction (the TIO footer shows both the output fraction and its decimal equivalent). Managed to beat the super straightforward `Sum[-4(-1)^j/(2j-1),{j,#}]&` by one byte by using powers of the complex unit `I` instead of powers of `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org), 26 bytes

```
[\+] (4,-*...*)Z/(1,3...*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1up4FCcWqhg@z86RjtWQcNER1dLT09PSzNKX8NQxxjM/G@tUJxYqaCkEq9gawdWHq0SH6ukkJZfpBBnaPAfAA)

This is an expression for the infinite sequence of partial sums.

- `(4, -* ... *)` is the sequence 4, -4, 4, -4, ....
- `(1, 3 ... *)` is the sequence 1, 3, 5, ....
- `Z/` zips those two sequences together using division.
- `[\+]` produces the sequence of partial sums.

Answer (score 1):

## x86 32-bit machine code, 23 bytes

```
D9 EE D9 E8 D9 E8 D8 C0 DC E9 D8 F1 DE E2 E2 F4 DD D8 D8 C0 D9 E1 C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLbTgIxEH2mXzGuIWlhISwmxoDrF@iLTyZqSLeXpUlpybaLi4Rfd21Z8IL2odM5czpzelI2Khlr20tlmK65gFvnubLj5R36BWlVnGOVMmXE0GJBfciK2ovFAmNJnWdUa0JAW1MCt3WhBUisjAdD5rCxioMwHJM5om4FGB4TjMaltgXVIJGc9aTm7yjuGapmXexJyjk4jyck7UKAXF3Ec/YD4mrzg5UdWdU6ZtNvnrZ2DVUs@vXX3X8m0MKhXiU8CoJniCQQRKP4khVV5vAkWpUsBbakFQwGIdkQtEMQViw2kMMkhW0M8wP6tlTBDTwcNnCbQ3ZNDmhc6@ColzjpTxWM7qA/zm7u5YtJUmjSYF9DSNfhxHsxD5QtlRHALBez5FhuvmdxC7sTG/qT6VPotc0xro1TpRH8oHpAJHluhsNXMt@f1P1hBLUXOZzDwZMzTYD7CoqtF450yo/14GBdmahrj9r2g0lNS9eOVlfTsIVPkIfrQn8C)

Following the `fastcall` calling convention, this takes a number `n` in ECX and returns the sum of the first `n` terms on the FPU register stack.

This code creates −2/1, −2/3, −2/5, ..., and combines them using the reverse-subtract instruction. This is equivalent to negating the running total before adding each term; this handles the alternating signs, but leaves the result with the wrong sign for odd `n`, which is corrected for by taking the absolute value at the end (because all the correct results are positive). The value is also doubled at the end.

In assembly:

```
                        # Example execution for i=2
                        # FPU register stack (left is bottom):
f:  fldz                # 0
    fld1                # 0   1
r:  fld1                # 0   1   1
    fadd st(0), st(0)   # 0   1   2
    fsub st(1), st(0)   # 0  -1   2
    fdiv st(0), st(1)   # 0  -1  -2/1
    fsubrp st(2), st(0) # -2/1  -1
    loop r              #[The loop executes again:
                        # -2/1  -1   1
                        # -2/1  -1   2
                        # -2/1  -3   2
                        # -2/1  -3  -2/3
                        # -2/3+2/1  -3            ]
    fstp st(0)          # -2/3+2/1
    fadd st(0), st(0)   # -4/3+4/1
    fabs                # -4/3+4/1   (but for odd n, this fixes the sign)
    ret
```

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 9 bytes

```
-´4÷1+2×↕
```

[Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=UCDihpAgLcK0NMO3MSsyw5fihpUKClDCqCAxK+KGlTY=)

#### Explanation

```
-´4÷1+2×↕
        ↕  Range [0, n)
      2×   Double each number
    1+     Add 1 to each number
  4÷       Divide 4 by each number
-´         Right fold on subtraction
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 62 bytes

```rust
fn f(n:f32,k:f32)->f32{if n==0.{return 4./k}4./k-f(n-1.,k+2.)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9NasMwFIT3OcXUi2ITSfEvFLsOlBAoFLLo1njhJDIYp0qQZCg1OkXprqfrRVwpONFiNIt535snB6WnqRVofZG3SUx6pwFdWx27FqIsQzZKrgcpkLJVb5xQm6YRI/0yZoFx4x9NJ/wA4wL2nbgG/7zwg@ZHlKiUPuYOm@e7lx2xGIInhhUSa7LYuSizNgnTqw8zVhdX0OEslMbmdbt5277nqB6VlgXi2kG9v98fj8B@394cb88SAp1AyFg6d7n1UXbGtkaj4M5ExILiHrjITuiTePC90YCuYXU0Fi4IFLntr3xfgd4Pq8QyqgPW7JW9@xkRp1ng6IPqvng9w83CTP8)

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 34 bytes

```
f=@(n)sum(4./[1:4:2*n,-(3:4:2*n)])
```

An anonymous function that makes an array of [ 1 5 9 ... -3 -7 -11 ...], member-wise divides 4 by the array and then sums the result.

Test:

```
arrayfun(f, 1:4)
  ans = 4.0000    2.6667    3.4667    2.8952
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Math++](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Math%2B%2B), 49 bytes

```
?>x
1>a
1>b
k+b*4/a>k
a+2>a
-b>b
x-1>x
4+5*!x>$
k
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 33 bytes

```
0$\~n;
(?\:2%2*1-4*$:}2*1-,+$1-:1
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/30Alpi7PmkvDPsbKSNVIy1DXREvFqhbE0NFWMdS1Mvz//79umQkA)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 22 bytes

```
sum(4/seq((1-2I)(-1)^I,I,1,Ans
```

Takes input in `Ans`. The first `-` is the subtraction sign, and the second is the negative sign. Only works for inputs less than or equal to 999, or 99 on a TI-83. For larger inputs, use this:

#### 29 bytes

```
Input N
For(I,1,N
Ans+4(-1)^I/(1-2I
End
Ans
```

The first `-` is the negative sign, and the second is the subtraction sign. Assumes being run on fresh/RAM cleared calculator.

Answer (score 1):

## APL (Dyalog Unicode), 10 bytes

```
4×-/÷1+2×⍳
```

[Try it on TryAPL.org!](https://tryapl.org/?clear&q=%E2%8E%95IO%E2%86%900%20%E2%8B%84%204%C3%97-%2F%C3%B71%2B2%C3%97%E2%8D%B34&run)

The environmental variable ⎕IO←0.

A tacit function.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
*4smc^_1dhy
```

[Test suite](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=%2a4smc%5E_1dhy&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4&debug=0)

###### Explanation:

```
*4smc^_1dhy   | Full code
*4smc^_1dhydQ | with implicit variables
--------------+
   m        Q | For each d from 0 to input:
    c^_1dhyd  |  (-1)^d/(2d+1)
  s           | Sum the results
*4            | Print sum * 4
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$11\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 9.054 bytes

```
S\n2@N{hax4
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJTXFxuMkBOe2hheDQiLCIzIl0=)

I spent so long golfing this just to beat Husk. No `hax` used.

```
S\n2@N{hax4
        ax  # Range [1, n]
       h    # Double
      {     # Subtract 1
    @N      # Negate
  n2        # Every other element
 \        4 # 4 divided by the list
S           # Sum
```

Comment: [0.054 bytes less](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/252030/calculating-%cf%80-using-the-gregory-leibniz-series-until-n-terms#comment578097_252103)...

Answer (score 0):

**ABAP**

```
    SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b0.
    PARAMETERS: p_in TYPE i OBLIGATORY.
    SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b0.

    START-OF-SELECTION.

    DATA: v_result      TYPE float.
    PERFORM calculate USING p_in CHANGING v_result.
    WRITE / v_result.

    FORM calculate USING v_in TYPE i
                   CHANGING v_result TYPE float.

      DATA: v_exponent,
            v_denominator,
            v_next  TYPE i.

      IF v_in = 1.
        v_result = v_result + 4.
        RETURN.
      ELSE.
        v_exponent = v_in + 1.
        v_denominator = ( 2 * v_in ) - 1.
        v_result = v_result + ( 4 * ( -1 ** v_exponent ) ) / v_denominator.
        v_next = v_in - 1.
        PERFORM calculate USING v_next CHANGING v_result.
      ENDIF.
```

ENDFORM.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Answers here need to be golfed (shortened), which you can do by removing whitespace and shortening variable names.

Comment: And besides you'll need to add your score in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 42 bytes

```powershell
1.."$args"|%{$s+=(-4,4)[$_%2]/(2*$_-1)}
$s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5bS8NAEIXf91cMZStZ3V2bi1oLgUipb6K0jyGEdN0aJJKS2aCQ5rfHXExa8LzNOWe@mWP@rQtMdZYJlRe6oQe/amwpZzQpPnB2mlcUb3xLeNxjIY3nTnRrOdc0FjarCcWmJiSwCLTigWVz8Ng4OBwceT/qYfJdDq70/vte118@3jnu0maEwQme82KTqFS87j@1MlD1TWo0mnWCmgPVP8c20O/gA42HtNBYZqY1rujh3CV9GL7t1iWa/GsARsFA7LQrldKI7V74kpg0Wq2e9midD4iRzEC0@IVcdLKn/e149q82BZuLF0daH9akbn4B)

Answer (score 0):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 44 bytes

```
/
 M /e!]4aaE*R!0~w~?R.![?2+.!]:+~t.$K;\ O @
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1@fS8FXQT9VMdYkMdFVK0jRoK68zj5ITzHa3khbTzHWSruuRE/F2zpGwV/B4f///yYA)

`Alice` does not support decimal, so instead of doing decimal, I'll output an integer, starting from `4e10`:

```
1 - 40000000000
2 - 26666666666
3 - 34666666666
4 - 28952380951
```

Please let me know if not OK and I'll withdraw the answer.

#### Explanation

```
/M/4aaE*R!]e![0~w~?R.!]?2+.![:+~t.$K;\O@   Flattened
/M/                                        Reads an argument and pushes it into the stack
   4aaE*R!]e![                             Write two entries `-40000000000` and `-1` in the tape
              0                            Pushes 0 on the stack, we will sum the other terms of the series onto it
               ~w~             ~t.$K       Loops until we have repeated the loop `argument` times
                  ?R.!]?2+.![              From the tape, negate the first argument and add `2` to the second and update the tape with their new values
                             :+            Divide them (forms the nth term of the series) and add it to the series' sum
                                    ;\O@   Outputs the result and finishes
```

Answer (score 0):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 32 bytes

```
[1+range(.*2)|drem(.;2)*4/.]|add
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oq3DBgqWlJWm6FjcVog21ixLz0lM19LSMNGtSilJzNfSsjTS1TPT1YmsSU1Ig6qDKF2wx5DLiMuYy4TLlMuMy57LgsuQyNIDIAQA)

Answer (score 0):

## k, 17 bytes

```
+/(n#4 -4)%1+2*!n
```

`1+2*!n` generate the denominators

`n#4 -4` generate the numerators

`%` vector division

`+/` sum

Answer (score 0):

## PARI/GP 32 bytes

```
p(n)=sum(k=s=1,n,4/(1-2*k)*s=-s)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ıḌ⁻4\n⁺u@×
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNCVCMSVFMSVCOCU4QyVFMiU4MSVCQjQlNUNuJUUyJTgxJUJBdSU0MCVDMyU5NyZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTQmZmxhZ3M9Uw==)

##### Explanation

```python
ıḌ⁻4\n⁺u@×  # Implicit input
ı           # Map over [1..n]:
   4\       #  4 divided by...
 Ḍ⁻         #  (2 * n - 1)
         ×  #  Multiplied by
       u@   #  -1 to the power of...
     n⁺     #  (n + 1)
            # Implicit output of sum
```